# Eucalyptus error on volume attached: ncAttachVolumeMarshal

Tags: eucalyptus

have created a volume and when I tried to attach the volume, I run this command:

```
euca-attach-volume -i i-3C66428A -d /dev/sdf vol-639C3E6C
```

After theat when I tried euca-describe-volumes it says failed. I have checked my cc.log but it seems like it has no error in it. So I have checked in `nc.log` and got this error in nc.log.

```
ERROR 000003074 ncAttachVolumeMarshal    | [i-F7893F67][vol-8C9741E9] failed error=1
```

What do I have to do to fix it? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug as I have get one similar posted in https://eucalyptus.atlassian.net/browse/EUCA-6201:

```
2013-05-15 19:35:58 ERROR 000011295 ncAttachVolumeMarshal    | [i-116D3ECC][vol-A51C3B6E] failed error=1
```